# Update raster values using Python

Tags: python, raster, python-xarray, rasterio

I'm trying to read in a raster file. It's a 32-bit float raster, with either values 1 or no data. I want to update the values of 1 to 10, and write it out again (probably as a UNIT8 data type?). Here is my attempt:

```
import rioxarray
import numpy
my_rast = rioxarray.open_rasterio("my_file.tif", masked=True, cache=False)
my_rast[numpy.where(my_rast == 1)] = 10
my_rast.rio.set_nodata(255)
my_rast.rio.to_raster("output.tif", compress='lzw', num_threads='all_cpus', tiled=True, 
dtype='uint8', driver="GTiff", predictor=2, windowed=True)
```

However the fourth line never seems to finish (maybe as it's a fairly large raster?). I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the result of `print(my_rast)`:

```
<xarray.DataArray (band: 1, y: 1140, x: 1053)>
[1200420 values with dtype=float64]
Coordinates:
  * band         (band) int64 1
  * x            (x) float64 9.412 9.412 9.412 9.413 ... 9.703 9.704 9.704 9.704
  * y            (y) float64 47.32 47.32 47.32 47.32 ... 47.0 47.0 47.0 47.0
    spatial_ref  int64 0
Attributes:
    AREA_OR_POINT:  Area
    scale_factor:   1.0
    add_offset:     0.0
```

Comment: You could subset the data spatially and test it out to see if it does what you want and finishes. If so, something taking a long time isn’t result something we can help with. If the file continues to increase in size as it goes then it hasn’t stalled out or anything. But I don’t really see an answerable question here unless there’s an error…

Comment: It's not a huge file and it's been running for about 12 hours now, so I'm pretty sure that there are errors in my code. It's the WHERE clause on the 4th row where it gets stuck. Am I implementing it correctly?

Comment: How big is the file? Can you paste the results of `print(ds)` as a code block?

Comment: There isn't anything called ds. Do you mean my_rast ?

Comment: I've put it in the question above.

Comment: That’s not very big. What happens if you load the array first?

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: my_rast = my_rast.load() before anything else

Comment: If I load it first, it crashes on the *where* row (which is the one I figured it was getting stuck on before). The error is: 
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 48.3 PiB for an array with shape (189443, 189443, 189443) and data type float64

Comment: Oh! Sorry I see it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t use a 3D positional index like this:

```py
my_rast[numpy.where(my_rast == 1)] = 10
```

Instead, use [`xarray.DataArray.where`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.where.html):

```py
my_rast = my_rast.where(my_rast != 1, 10)
```

Indexing in xarray works slightly differently from numpy when providing array-like objects as indices - it’s worth giving the docs on [Vectorized Indexing](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/indexing.html#vectorized-indexing) and [More Advanced Indexing](//docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/indexing.html#more-advanced-indexing) a read.

Comment: This seems to work. Thank you. But I'm a bit confused by the where function. In the code you have written I would expect that values which ARE NOT 1, are turned into 10. But it's actually the opposite?

Comment: For da.where, the values in the array are retained when the condition is true; if false, they’re replaced with *other*

Comment: Got it thanks. That's a bit counter-intuitive IMHO. But ok.

Comment: It’s the same logic as [numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html). Where true give x, else y. In this case x is the array object itself.